# how to increment insert data into my database

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-nifi

I built a pipeline with apache NiFi using the processors:

ListSFTP-->FetchSFTP-->MergeContent-->contentText--ReplaceText-->updateAttribute-->PutSQL.

- ListSFTP and FetchSFTP allow me to connect to remote servers to collect data,
- MergeContent allows me to merge files by file type to have a single document to count lines by file type.
- CountText allows me to count the lines.
- ReplaceText allows me to retrieve the attributes I need.
- updateAttribute to update the attributes.
- PutSQL allows me to insert the number of rows and the number of files collected by type.

My problem is that when I launch the collection I have several values in the database for the same type of files. I want to have only one value for the day for each type of files. For one day when I collect data the value in the database will be updated (increment).someone can help me.

```
 id | file       | line 
----+------------+------------+
  1 |        194 |            |
  2 |        116 |            |
  3 |        164 |            |
  4 |        106 |            |
  5 |         48 |            |
  6 |         18 |            |
  7 |          8 |            |
  8 |          1 |            |
  9 |          1 |            |
 10 |          3 |            |
 
I wish to have since it is the result of three types of files collected.
 id | file                 | line 
----+----------------------+------------+
  1 |   194+106+8+3=311    |            |
  2 |   116+48+1    =165   |            |
  3 |   164+18+1 =183      |            |

 id | file  | line 
----+-------+------------+
  1 |   311 |            |
  2 |  165  |            |
  3 |  183  |            |
  Configuration of MergeContent.
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: so it means MergeContent is not doing its job properly. and It's not easy to troubleshoot with no information provided for it in your question

Comment: also from nifi documentations?: `It is recommended that the Processor be configured with only a single incoming connection, as Group of FlowFiles will not be created from FlowFiles in different connections.`

Comment: I have reconfigured with only one incoming flowfile but I have the same problem. How can I configure the MergeContent processor to fix this error.

Comment: share your MergeContent configs

Comment: Hi eshirvana, I added the MergeContent processor configuration.

Comment: shouldn't you go with "defragment" for Merge Strategy?

Comment: hi eshirvana, When I set the merge strategy to "defragment" I get errors in my pipeline.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.a.n.processors.standard.MergeContent MergeContent[id=e76b89ab-017a-1000-fc21-f997c738397e] Failed to process bundle of 0 files due to java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: hmm... not sure about that, but If you figured it out ,let us know

Comment: hi eshirvana, I have another concern. Can we decode ASN1 files using a NiFi processor.

Comment: I think yes , It's pretty common file format.I never tried them personally though